# How to update two different React component instances that represent the same data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Say I've defined a `<Tag>` component that has two props: `id` and `name`. My application renders this component in two different places, so I have a `<Tag>` component whose id is `1` appearing twice, but whose owners are different. One tag is owned by an `<Entries>` component, and the other is owned by a `<Tags>` component.

When a `<Tag>` is clicked, I want to change its state, and I want all other `<Tag>` components with the same `id` to also change their state so that they match. What's the best way to do this? Should all `<Tags>` have the same root component? I don't like that idea, because I feel like it's a brittle solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options to go:

1- React way

- You should keep the state in a common owner component of `<Tags>` and `<Entries>`.
- You should pass a change handler from the state owner component to the `<Tag>` component
- When the tag changes the state owner will update `<Tag>`s in both `<Tags>` and `<Entries>`
- Reading this should give you a lot of insight:
  http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

2- Pure Flux way

- If your application is a little more complex than what you have told you can go with flux architecture.
- To do this you should have actions,dispatchers and stores implemented in your application.
- When a `<Tag>` is changed you call an action, which in turn calls a dispatcher, which is in turn listened by stores, which in turn emits a change event to components. Then all the components updates themselves with the new state.
- You can find about flux here:
  http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html

Comment: Thanks. I like option 2 the best, since I'm already using the Flux pattern :) I'm trying to get this working with actions/stores/dispatchers now, and think it'll do the trick.

Answer (score -3):

id's should generally be unique within an html document.
The best solution would be to change your id's to classes.